# Attempted import error: 'OBJLoader' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE')

Tags: reactjs, animation, three.js

while i try to run  OBJLoader it give the error. Attempted import error: 'OBJLoader' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').

```
     import * as THREE from "three";
     import OBJLoader from "three-obj-loader";
     OBJLoader(THREE);

         const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
              75,
              window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
              0.1,
              1000
            );
        
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            this.mount.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        
           const loader = new OBJLoader();

            loader.load(
              "model/Room.obj",
              function (object) {
                scene.add(object);
              },
              function (xhr) {
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
              },
              function (error) {
                console.log("An error happened");
              }
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copy/pasting the whole module of `'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';` (check in the source repo or node module folder) in my current project structure

Then import as you'd usually do

```js
import { OBJLoader } from './OBJLoader'
```

Answer (score 2):

Please import `OBJLoader` like so:

```js
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
```

The usage of `three-obj-loader` is not required. All example files are available as modules in the `three` npm package.

Comment: when i run it didnt give output and show this error  index.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFLoader.parse (GLTFLoader.js:281)
    at Object.onLoad (GLTFLoader.js:174)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.module.js:36513)

Comment: This error is an indicator that your server does not serve JS files correctly. Please make a google search for this, there should be multiple threads about this issue.

Comment: Infinity% loaded
OBJLoader.js:716 THREE.OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "<!DOCTYPE html>"
parse @ OBJLoader.js:716
(anonymous) @ OBJLoader.js:455
(anonymous) @ three.module.js:36513

Comment: Looks like the same issue. The loader does not not receive a proper OBJ file from the server but a HTML document.

Comment: three.min.js:2 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D

Comment: any idea to resolve this bug three.min.js:2 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D –

Comment: Sorry, but it's best if you ask a new question for this. Also share your code otherwise it's not possible to help since this error could be triggered for 1000s of reasons.